# How do I load the data from my NSMutableDictionary to my UITableView

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

```
dictionaryOfWebsites = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dictionaryOfWebsites setObject:@"http://www.site1.com" forKey:@"Site1"];
[dictionaryOfWebsites setObject:@"http://www.site2.com" forKey:@"Site2"];
[dictionaryOfWebsites setObject:@"http://www.site3.com" forKey:@"Site3"];
[dictionaryOfWebsites setObject:@"http://www.site4.com" forKey:@"Site4"];
```

Above is my dictionary. I want to have a tableview where the text in the UITableViewCell will say "Site1" and the subtext will have the URL.

I know this will get me all the keys

```
NSArray *keys = [dictionaryOfWebsites allKeys];

// values in foreach loop
for (NSString *key in keys) {
    NSLog(@"%@ is %@",key, [dict objectForKey:key]);
}
```

you're help would be greatly appreciated

If my approach is not the best one, please let me know so I can learn from your recommendations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [[dictionaryOfWebsites allKeys] count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Initialize cell of style subtitle
    NSArray *keys = [[dictionaryOfWebsites allKeys]sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
    NSString *key = keys[indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = key;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = dictionaryOfWebsites[key];

    return cell;
}
```

Edit : It is better to have an array of dictionaries for these kind of representation.

Each dictionary with two key value pairs Title and Subtitle.

```
self.dataArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"Title":@"Site1",@"Subtitle":@"http://www.site1.com"};
[dataArray addObject:dict];
//Add rest of the dictionaries to the dataArray


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.dataArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Initialize cell of style subtitle

    NSDictionary *dict = self.dataArray[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = dict[@"Title"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = dict[@"Subtitle"];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Using `-[NSDictionary allKeys]` is not a good idea since the order of keys is not guaranteed to remain same across multiple calls. From the docs: `The order of the elements in the array is not defined.`.

Comment: @Mar0ux Exactly, I gave another suggestion to remove this. If the nature of keys are known a sorting can be done to remove this.

Comment: Ok. I would recommend removing the first solution or modifying it to include sorting lest people copy paste that code directly.

Comment: @Mar0ux I have edited my answer to include sorting. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 //cell initialization code
 NSString *title = [keys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 cell.textLabel.text = title;
 cell.detailTextLabel.text = [dictionaryOfWebsites objectForKey:title];

 return cell;
}
```

in that case declare keys array as a property.